# Xamarin and gRPC: connection close by peer

Tags: xamarin.android, grpc

I am trying to do some tries with xamarin android and gRPC.

I have my service running in my computer, and I have a net standard 2.1 library with the gRPC client. If I use this library in a wpf application in the same computer, I get response from server, but if I use this library in my xamarin proyect, that I run in a virtual machine with android 8.0, I get the message error connection closed by peer.

In the xamarion prject, the address that I am using is https://10.0.2.2:5001. I am using the IP 10.0.2.2 because if I am not wrong, it is the IP that is used to communicate with localhost.

How could I solve this problem?

Thanks.

PD: I have set permissions to application to can use internet.

PD: I have realized that if my WPF application I use https://localhost:5001 it works, but if I use https:x.x.x.x:5001 where x.x.x.x is the IP of the computer, it gives the same error.

Comment: when using a secure connection ("https"), the hostname you use actually matters. So if you're able to connect with https://localhost:5001 and X.X.X.X:5001 fails, the problem is likely how your SSL certificate is setup (it includes name "localhost" but doesn't allow using the raw IP.)     Enabling extra logging could help debug the problem: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin works with native nugets [Grpc.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Core/) and [Grpc.Core.Api](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Core.Api/)
It wont work with Grpc.Net.Client

Find more on
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/client?view=aspnetcore-3.1

> Calling gRPC over HTTP/2 with Grpc.Net.Client is currently not supported on Xamarin. We are working to improve HTTP/2 support in a future Xamarin release. Grpc.Core and gRPC-Web are viable alternatives that work today.